# rxjs pairwise is emitting duplicate values

Tags: angular, rxjs, pairwise

I'm trying to create two scroll event observable for both scroll direction vertical and horizontal.

I tried using `pairwise()` and `bufferCount(2,1)` operators to filter vertical scroll event from the horizontal one, but the problem is with getting duplicate values for `prev.scrollTop` and `curr.scrollTop`

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { pairwise, tap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('scrollable', {static: false}) scrollable: ElementRef;


  ngAfterViewInit() {

    fromEvent(this.scrollable.nativeElement, 'scroll').pipe(
      pairwise(),
      tap(([prev, curr]) => console.log(prev.target.scrollTop, curr.target.scrollTop)),
      filter(([prev, curr]) => prev.target.scrollTop !== curr.target.scrollTop),
      tap((e) => console.log(e)) // <=    Never reached
    ).subscribe();

  }

}
```

Any ideas?

[stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5zqlsj)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's because you pairwised the nativeElement, which is always referencing the same object. So basically you have to `pluck` your desire primitive value.

```
  fromEvent(this.scrollable.nativeElement, 'scroll').pipe(
      pluck('target','scrollTop'),
      pairwise(),
      tap(([prev, curr]) => console.log(prev,curr)),
      filter(([prev, curr]) => prev!== curr),
      tap((e) => console.log(e)) // <=    Never reached
    ).subscribe();
```

Comment: This throws Error: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined, can you try your solution with the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5zqlsj

Comment: try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3w6vrh?file=src/app/app.component.ts